# System error 5 Access is denied when starting a .NET service

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, error-handling, windows-services

When I try to start a service I created in Visual Studio I receive the following error:

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

I am running the command line with elevated privileges, so it's not that problem. Is there any place I can look to see what error is occuring.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To get it to work I needed to add permissions to the output bin\debug folder for my service project.

The Local Service account didn't have permissions to the output .exe file, and this was why the error was occuring.

Comment: Silly thing really.  I simply ran the install from the debug folder which I thought would place the actual executable in the proper directory. The permissions did the trick.

Comment: Worked for me too - thanks. I just wanted to try it out and installing from a Debug folder was the lazy option :-)

Comment: It's a good thing that you posted this answer when you found the solution yourself. I had the same problem and it helped me. Thanks :-D

Comment: Possible you could elaborate on the steps required to fix this?

Comment: Good day can anyone please elaborate this. What do you mean by add permission to the bin/debug. Thanks.

Comment: Steps required are outlined here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978054/cannot-start-windows-service-in-networkservice-account/11983513#11983513

Answer (score 18):

Had the same issue.

Fixed by running the service under "Local System Account"

[image]

Answer (score 14):

In my case the solution was even that simple: Run Command Prompt as *administrator*.

Comment: But when you try to schedule your service through task schedule, this solution will not work.

Answer (score 10):

I see you've fixed the problem; but in reality, you shouldn't normally be running the service from a project's bin folder anyway - the files should be put somewhere project and profile independent (for example, under program files). For debugging purposes (when it *will* be in the bin folder), you can detect whether it is a service in `Main()`, and if it is being run interactively just run the service code directly, rather than the usual service-start setup.

You can detect either by adding a command line argument, or you can *try* checking `Environment.UserInteractive`.

Comment: Yea, in my scenario is was in DEV, and a post-build event deploys and starts the service for me, ready for me to attach to it.

Comment: This is true, but it's also important to debug the service running as the Local Service user, otherwise you might run into unexpected permissions issues when running in production.

Comment: Marc's suggestion is the proper way to do it :) If you just want to get past the error, then see the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

The Local Services account doesn't seem to be privileged to control a service. So, in the service's LogOn Property, change the account type to Local System and allow service to interact with desktop.

Also, make sure that, you install the service using instalutil, as an administrator.

Lastly, when you want to run a service from the command prompt using the "net start [service name]" command, you have to run the command prompt as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because my project and its source code was in a folder that had NTFS's Encrypting File System ([EFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System)) enabled. This caused by compiled assemblies being encrypted aswell and the user running my service didn't have permissions to decrypt them. Removing EFS was the easy solution for this. It can be done by command line using CIPHER.EXE, which is a Windows tool.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not simply start the service under a different username or admin**. (Unless your service actually requires admin privileges of course!) This is a security hole and creates a bad user experience.

The actual issue is that the service hasn't been assigned any permissions in the first place.

However, it must be noted that Microsoft didn't exactly make them easy to change - service permissions are similar to regular file permissions but unfortunately cannot be altered with a simple right click. They can however be read via:

```
sc.exe sdshow <service name>
```

And written via:

```
sc.exe sdset <service name> <permissions>
```

- `<service name>` is your service name.
- `<permissions>` is the permissions in SDDL format.

So use `sdshow` to get the permissions, then `sdset` to update them with your requirement(s). SDDL a cacophony of seemingly random letters beyond the scope of this post and more reminiscent of Unix than Windows.
In short instance adding the descriptor `(A;;RPWP;;;WD)` would allow (`A`) everyone (`WD`) to start (`RP`) and stop (`WP`) the named service.

Comment: There is a small utility with a graphical interface that greatly simplifies editing permissions: https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceSecurityEditor/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I migrated a service from vs05 to vs2010, from framework 2.0 till framework 4.0 at the same time. I got Access denied. As soon as a change back to framework 2.0 it worked again. The ?%¤#%&%& problem was that the initializing string for the service was incorrect (?!). The string expected quotes at the beginning and at the end!

Before....path + service name" "/parameter=1   ' this had worked with framework 2.0

After...."path + service name" "/parameter=1"

Access Denied has nothing to do with the problem. Why not "Path not found " or "missing parameter"

Answer (score 0):

Run it from Task Scheduler with highest privileges and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

A user account with administrator rights will prompt “are you sure?” in situations where the administrator account is not prompted. I had this problem with net stop netprofm.

To remove the prompt do this.

Control Panel, User Accounts, Change User Account Control settings, never notify

This seems to provide the user account with admin rights the same behavior as a the administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue after I had run an 'sc config' to change binPath of the service.

The only fix that worked for me was to 'sc delete' the service and install again.

Things worked perfectly after that.