# .NET C# Windows Service Error 'ERROR 5'

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

Real simple, made this windows service:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx

Installed it, console shows no problems, navigate to *Computer Management, Services and Applications, Services* find my Service, Right Click - Start and this bad boy comes up.

[image: Error Box]

I have tried building it as Release and Debug, moving the file to a new folder and even looking at different answers on here :
[System error 5 Access is denied when starting a .NET service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574411/system-error-5-access-is-denied-when-starting-a-net-service)

[Windows Service : error 5 :Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615367/windows-service-error-5-access-denied)

And no luck. This has been driving me mad. Please help
*Muchas Gracias*

Comment: Under what account is the service configured to run ?

Comment: It says LOCAL SERVICE I think. 

First time doing Services so excuse me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the concept of a .Net service, so there is something in your environment that is preventing this to work. It is hard to debug from a distance.

Verify that :

1. You have administrator privileges
2. The default [auto-elevate rules](http://lab.technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd822916) of "Computer Management" still apply (in doubt, rigth click and select "Run as an administrator"
3. That the LOCAL SERVICE account has access to the binary. You can get a text version (easy to paste in a SO question) with `cacls path-to-your-service.exe`

Comment: EDIT Found solution thanks to you. Thank you very much dear sir. It was that it was LOCAL SERVICE instead of LOCAL SYSTEM.