# Cannot Start Windows Service in NetworkService account

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, network-service

I have a windows service project implementation that I am trying to install as network service.

```
process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
process.Account = ServiceAccount.NetworkService;
```

however whenever I try to start the service I get :

```
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

This comes after running the `net start MyService` command in the visual studio command prompt which is running as administrator by the way.

Any help on how to get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: Check the installation path, make sure that the [NetworkService user account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has all the privileges required by your service and that the folder has permissions for execution for NS user. Try putting a `Debug.Break` on the first line of the Windows Service `OnStart` method. Is it being hit?

Comment: no, the main method is not even being hit

Comment: Did you add permissions for NS user in that folder? Does it have "ticks" for Allow Execution?

Comment: @oleksii: I am just new to this windows service stuff so I am not sure I understand what you are talking about

Comment: @oleksii: do you want to add an answer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would check that the Network Service account has permissions to execute. Steps to check:

1. In Windows explorer go to the folder containing the binaries of the service
2. Right-click on the folder > Properties > Security tab > Edit button
3. Add > "NETWORK SERVICE" > OK
4. Give it full control (just to test and then reduce permissions till it working)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In My case above steps are not working. I have given the full rights to the Network service account and when I start service got error message "Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."

Comment: @user2323308 that's your inner exception. Not the absence of rights of Network Service.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the CLI?

Comment: @kkirsche I believe there is a way. See this article: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-caclsexe-to-view-and-manage-windows-acls/. If you figure it out, could you please update my answer with the details of the command and parameters? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Net Start MyService` is probably not running with escalated privileges.  Your command requires (I believe) Administrative Privileges.

**Update**

Not sure why, but your privileges on your service are weird.  By default privileges of services should look like:

```
D:(A;CI;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)

ACE Type: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
Trustee: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
AccessMask:
  ADS_RIGHT_DELETE
  ADS_RIGHT_READ_CONTROL
  ADS_RIGHT_WRITE_DAC
  ADS_RIGHT_WRITE_OWNER
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_CREATE_CHILD
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_DELETE_CHILD
  ADS_RIGHT_ACTRL_DS_LIST
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_SELF
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_READ_PROP
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_WRITE_PROP
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_DELETE_TREE
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_LIST_OBJECT
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_CONTROL_ACCESS
```

However your's looks like:

```
D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)

ACE Type: ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE
Trustee: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
AccessMask:
  ADS_RIGHT_READ_CONTROL
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_CREATE_CHILD
  ADS_RIGHT_ACTRL_DS_LIST
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_SELF
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_READ_PROP
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_WRITE_PROP
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_DELETE_TREE
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_LIST_OBJECT
  ADS_RIGHT_DS_CONTROL_ACCESS
```

I'm not sure exactly how that came to be.  Try uninstalling and reinstalling?

You can download SddlParse (google it :) to parse out the [Security Descriptor Definition Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: but i mention that visual studio cmd is running in admin mode

Comment: You've changed the shortcut to `Run As Aministrator`?  Also in the VS Command prompt type `sc sdshow MyService` and update your question with it's response.

Comment: running this sc command I get the following: `D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCR
RC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)`

Comment: I get this from regular cmd prompt run in admin mode: `D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCR
RC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)`

Answer (score -1):

The "Access denied" message applies to the user trying to start the service, not the account in which the service is run.

Can you start the service from:

1. the Services Control Panel applet?
2. an elevated command prompt you started yourself (not from Visual Studio)?

Comment: then how can I run the service fine in LocalSystem mode?

Comment: I also get access denied from the cmd prompt started by me

Comment: How about from the Services applet? Not sure what you mean by "LocalSystem mode". You can have the service run in the LocalSystem account by selecting the top radio-button: http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/services-control-panel-log-on-tab.jpg