# windows could not start service on local computer error 5 access is denied

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

After debugging and installing windows service in windows 8 I have error when I try to start a windows service :"The Windows could not start service on local computer Error 5 Access is denied" .While attempting fist answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267051/error-5-access-denied-when-starting-windows-service) i found that  NETWORK SERVICE account doesn't exist in the list of user names for assigning the correct permissions in windows 8 .How i can solve this problem using windows 8?

Comment: Is anything written to the event viewer or used proc mon (a sysinternals tools) to see what the access issue is?

Answer (score 59):

Right click in the service in Window Services and go to **Properties**. Then go to **Log On** tab and select **Local System account**. Click on **Ok** button and start the service.

Comment: That was pretty easy. Not sure about the checkbox of allow service to interact with desktop.

Comment: Didn't help in my case.

Comment: This is dangerous advice depending on the service. Many services need to run as a less privileged user than Local System or Administrator.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error due to the executable that the service was pointed at being missing, in my case it had been removed by the Anti Virus on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps- [Cannot Start Windows Service in NetworkService account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978054/cannot-start-windows-service-in-networkservice-account/11983513#11983513).

Click on Edit -> Search for NETWORK SERVICE -> Add that. Then provide necessary permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read these instructions: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/access-is-denied-local-services-windows-8-1.  It involves you changing the permissions in the Registry, then rebooting your system.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Event Viewer in Windows for more details on the error. In my case, the application could not login to the database. Giving it a 5. Acces Denied error.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to uninstall the service, Install it again as administrator. Now run it. it should work.